# How to loop over azure blob storage locations in Databricks and process files into dataframes?

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, avro, azure-databricks

i have a file system created by event hubs and it saves files to a location every 10 minutes in this format:
**{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}.avro**

Example:
**eventhub/eventhubservice/0/2022/01/01/01/11/31.avro**

There's 2 partitions: 0 and 1 and then the rest is the date format as above.

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop over every folder structure, take the avro file, change it into a df and then put it somewhere a lot more sensible.

However, I can't figure it out and not really got anywhere with it. I've gotten as far as:

```
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/mount-name/eventhub/eventhubservice/0/2022/01/01/01/11/31.avro')


df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/mnt/mount-name/eventhub/eventhubservice/0/2022/01/01/01/11/31.avro")
display(df)
```

Has anyone done something like this before in Azure Databricks?

Comment: Is the schema of all those files same?

Comment: yes the schema is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use glob file path while reading the data into a dataframe. I have the following folder structure where each of the folder has a csv file for demonstration.

[image]

- Now, to read all the files inside these folders into a dataframe, I have used the code in the following way with glob file path.

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True).format("csv").load("/mnt/repro/2022/10/*/*.csv")
#both the files have same data for demonstration
df.show()
```

[image]

- So, wherever there are multiple folders/files inside a folder, replace it with `*` indicating all of the contents. Use the following code:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/mnt/mount-name/eventhub/eventhubservice/*/2022/*/*/*/*/*.avro")
display(df)
#for year 2022.
```